# CO2 All Gone - Leaked through tap?

Tags: co2

I've had my CO2 tank hooked up to a 3-keg keezer for 6 months with no issue - and then one day I went downstairs and the CO2 is empty - but I haven't used nearly enough for it to be empty - and last time I checked the gauge (a week ago) there was plenty of gas left.

My question is - is it possible for one of my taps (perlicks) to be open enough to leak out co2, but not to be dripping beer?  Is there a chance that's how I lost the gas?

Thanks!

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [CO2 tank slowly losing gas, not sure where the problem lies](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10234/co2-tank-slowly-losing-gas-not-sure-where-the-problem-lies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for CO2 to escape from the tap without pushing beer out as well. If there's a leak, it probably in the regulator, manifold, quick disconnects, or one of the kegs. Tighten all the clamps and connectors, and check your seals.

Comment: Thank you - I'll check things over and hopefully track it down

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you pour a beer, more CO2 goes into the keg to fill the space the beer had been occupying. Assuming you used the tank to carbonate and serve beer from all 3 kegs, you could have used it all up. The amount of time this takes depends on how big your CO2 tank is obviously. Different systems go through CO2 at different amounts. I always check for leaks in my setup by spraying the connections and lid with a little foamy StarSan (shake up the spray bottle first) and I don't see bubbles, but I go through a 5lb tank on a 2 keg system every few months.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. It is a leak, but highly unlikely it is through the tap. In most cases I've had it be the quick disconnects on the kegs. Those little rubber seals (I use ball lock) can crack pretty easy letting small leaks form that are hard to notice. So what I've started doing is taking a closer look at them and replacing them periodically.

One way to save your gas in this situation: shut it off when you aren't using it. Flip off the gas at the tank, and each manifold if you're using one. If you have a leak you may lose pressure in one of your kegs for example, but at least you aren't draining a tank of gas.

Comment: Thanks for the good tip - if I flip the switches on the distributor as well, I'll be able to tell which tank is losing the gas too based on how much it takes